# CSS pseudo class. Dynamic height arrows

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I have menu items which are to be styled as follows:

[image]

The arrow at the end I am achieving with an :after pesudo-class:

```
.ride-type-menu:after{
        content:"";
        border: 13px solid;
        border-color:  transparent #DBD7D7;
        border-right-color: transparent;
        right: -26px;
        top: 0;
        position: absolute;
        display: block;
    }
```

The issue I have is when these menu items stretch down onto multiple lines:

[image]

Can anyone think of a way (even with an image if necessary) that I can increase the height (keeping the width) of the arrow automatically based on the number of lines the menu item takes up to achieve something like this:

[image]

Comment: Immediately this problem strikes me as one that JavaScript could handle pretty easily. I'm racking my brain for a CSS solution. Maybe playing with `height: 100%;` could help. I'm on my iPhone or I'd test it myself for you. Also, you should set up a JSFiddle!

Comment: Pretty sure `border-width` determines the size of the arrow so to get something like this to work you'd need to get the height of the container then divide it by 2 or some such trickery like this I'm thinking..

Comment: Update: This is impossible.. You can't even remotely manipulate pseudo elements in javascript as they are not even part of the DOM.

Comment: @mdk, good point! Fraser, you could use a Unicode character to display the triangle, then apply a `transform` to it. But that wouldnt have IE support, and it runs the risk of being non-semantic. I'll keep thinking!

Comment: I think unfortunately since border-width cannot take a percentage this doesn't seem possible with CSS alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one idea on how you could do this, use an SVG image for the `li` background, then resize it using the CSS `background-size` property. This works in IE 9, Firefox, Safari and Chrome however it looks a little bit funky in Opera (there maybe a fix?).

First, you'll need the SVG XML, save the following in a new text file, save it as 'right-arrow.svg'

**SVG**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.1"
   width="152.18813"
   height="175.7317"
   id="svg2"
   preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     transform="translate(-37.842052,-201.63918)"
     id="layer1">
    <path
   d="m 37.842053,377.37089 -10e-7,-87.86586 0,-87.86585 76.094068,43.93293     76.09405,43.93293 -76.09406,43.93292 z"
       id="path2987"
       style="fill:#00f0ff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Then use this:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>first<br>second<br>third</li>
    <li>first<br>second</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none; }

li {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position:relative;
    width: 200px;
    background: url('right-arrow.svg') right center no-repeat;
    background-size: 15px 100%;
    padding: 15px;
}

li:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 215px; /* (li width + padding) - background-size width */
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #00f0ff;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Bit sloppy but you can refine this as you need, the idea is there.

Answer (score 2):

OK!  Hacky solution incoming!

You can do it with JS, by adding a rotated square element to your menu items. You need to calculate its size so that its diagonal length will be equivalent to the height of the menu item. You also need to set its position (you can do this statically in CSS) so that its top corner will be at the top edge of the menu item.

Here's a demo: http://jsbin.com/oxaxet/2/edit

The obvious problem with this is that the "width" of the rotated element grows along with the height of the parent element.  I believe it may be possible to <s>fix</s> hack further with the `skew` transform to address this, but this partial fix is all the math I can handle at the moment. If I poke at it again later I will edit my answer.

I don't think it's possible to do what you want with pseudoelements because 1) CSS is not programmatic, so you can't calculate sizes 2) JS cannot touch pseudoelements*, so once you do calculate the sizes, you can't apply them.

The closest I came with pure CSS (working with pseudoelements) was to use `top: 0` and `bottom: 0` (or `height: 100%` works too) on the `:after` to get its height the same as its parent, but after that there is no way to set the `border-width` value based on the parent's height, so the tip of the arrow gets cut off as the parent grows.

*iirc both limitations have obscure workarounds, but they never looked solid enough for me to remember. You can look up "calculate size CSS" or "javascript pseudoelements" yourself if you think you can hack further in those directions.